# What is P0Y0M0DT1H0M0 interval?

Tags: .net, vb.net, intervals

I am developing one application in which I have been given a interval as  "P0Y0M0DT1H0M0.000S" from client. I do not know what is this and how can I parse this?

I want to start time at P0Y0M0DT1H0M0.000S in my .net application. I want to know what this format means and is there any link available on internet where it is explained(obviously I searched before posting it here!)?

I also do not know under which Tags this question should go.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp check the Duration data type - P is for period

Comment: @Rup Okay, posted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably inspired by XML Duration data type as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp).

> The time interval is specified in the following form "PnYnMnDTnHnMnS"
>   where:
>
> - P indicates the period (required)
> - nY indicates the number of years
> - nM indicates the number of months
> - nD indicates the number of days
> - T indicates the start of a time section (required if you are going to specify hours, minutes, or seconds)
> - nH indicates the number of hours
> - nM indicates the number of minutes
> - nS indicates the number of seconds

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks for posting this. +1 and accepted as answer.